# Appending Rows in Excel with Different Column Order, but Same Column Name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, powerquery

I am trying to append two tables into one.
I will call them table 1 and table 2
Table 1 has more columns than table 2 because I have added them manually but other column names are the same in both tables. when I append them via power query. table 1s formula is removed and pasted as values automatically.
Is there any other way to append these tables? where formulas are not removed and I can subsequently drop the formula to the newly appended table.

Comment: You could probably solve this with formula's (INDEX MATCH) rather than power query. But maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/43743926/12634230

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a power query solution, but using formula (since you also tagged [excel-formula] and [office365]), you could use:

```
=LET(header,{"a","b","c"},
          A,A1:C3,
          B,E1:H4,
             rA,ROWS(A),
             rB,ROWS(B),
             ch,COLUMNS(header),
          headerA,INDEX(A,1,),
          headerB,INDEX(B,1,),
                          matchA,XMATCH(header,headerA),
                          matchB,XMATCH(header,headerB),
                                         cleanmatchA,FILTER(matchA,ISNUMBER(matchA)),
                                         cleanmatchB,FILTER(matchB,ISNUMBER(matchB)),
          dataA,INDEX(A,SEQUENCE(rA-1,,2),cleanmatchA),
          dataB,INDEX(B,SEQUENCE(rB-1,,2),cleanmatchB),
                      seqAB,SEQUENCE(rA+rB-1),
IFERROR(
                 IF(seqAB=1,
                     header,
                     IF(seqAB<=rA,
                                              INDEX(dataA,SEQUENCE(rA,,0),SEQUENCE(1,ch)),
                                              INDEX(dataB,seqAB-rA,SEQUENCE(1,ch)))),
                  ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "Add queries with the same column names, but different orders"

[`Append queries` in Power Query does exactly that.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries)

[image]

#### or

```
= Table.Combine({ Query1, Query2 })
```

#### Merge requirements

Power query is the opposite of what you're used to:

| Source | Requirement |
| --- | --- |
| Power Query | Columns of the same names, with different order |
| SQL / DAX | Columns in the same order, with different names |