# Power Query Function Date to Custom Column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to include the contents of a named range in a custom column in a power query.

I have created a named range cell in excel which holds a date value, then created a blank query with Function and am calling that into a custom column in another query - all based on this users question/answer [How can I reference a cell's value in a Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26989280/4294435).

When trying to call the function (named range) into the custom column in my query I am receiving an Expression.Error:

[image]

I have tried Date.ToText, formatting the column in Transform -> Data Type and receive the same error but with different messages, eg. instead of #datetime it would be value.

This is my line of code in advanced editor that is calling the named range (date).

```
 #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "Date2", each Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(GetDate("FNEndDate"))))
```

Comment: So what you are actually doing is trying to add a column to your table in which each row is a nested table with the contents of an Excel of which the path+file name is a date/time....
That won't work.
You'd better try and explain what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @MarcelBeug I have edited my original question. Hope this is a bit clearer. The link to the question shows the query for the function which is being used to call the named range cell into my power query custom column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add a column with the value from the named range, just remove the Excel.Workbook(File.Contents part:

```
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "Date2", each GetDate("FNEndDate"))
```