# How can I drive column titles from cell values outside of the query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have created a recurring (monthly) query tool.  Each month, the name of a column will change.  I would like the user to be able to type the value in a cell on the first sheet, and drive that value to become the title of a column in the table.

**Thought 1:**
Modify the following code:
`#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Multiplied Column7",{{"Month1;BDG", "AAA"}})`
to replace "AAA" with a call to a specific cell on another sheet directly in the "Renamed" step.  Is this possible?

**Thought 2:**
Manage the change as column data by doing the following:
 1. Demote the current column titles using "Use headers as first row"
 2. Write an IF statement if the value = "Column7" then "value of the cell on the other sheet" else [Column7].
 3. Then promote the top row to be column headers after the change.

Or is there a way easier way?  My searches have come up dry!

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in Excel that has the column name you want to use. For example, if you want "AAA", then put this in a couple cells in your sheet:

```
ColumnName
AAA
```

Select those two cells and go to Insert > Table and make it a table. (Check the box for "My table has headers".)

Under Design, you can name this table whatever you'd like, say, "ColNameTable".

Then in your code, you can use

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ColNameTable"]}[Content]{0}[ColumnName]
```

instead of `"AAA"`. I.E.

```
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Multiplied Column7",{{"Month1;BDG", Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ColNameTable"]}[Content]{0}[ColumnName]}})
```

This pulls in the value of the first row (index starts at zero) of the column named `ColumnName` in the table `ColNameTable` from your current workbook.

---

Note: You can also use named ranges instead of creating a new table. See here: [How can I reference a cell's value in a Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query)