# Pass parameter from a cell in excel workbook to SQL Query

Tags: excel, parameters, powerquery, excel-2016

Please note I have found solutions to this in `Excel 2007, 2010, 2013` etc but nothing that relates directly to `2016`.

I bring in a query to Excel by using `Data / Get Data / From Database / From SQL Server Database`.

What I want to do is restrict 1 column in the data it retrieves to a specific value.

In my exact example there is a date column and I want a cell in the spreadsheet to pass the date value to filter the returned query data.

Answer (score 0):

For this application, I don't think you need to actually pass the date as a parameter to your query. You can just use the date from the cell as a filter after you've loaded your query into the Query Editor. As a result of query folding, Excel should automatically pass it into the `WHERE` clause of the native query it sends to the SQL Server Database.

If you don't know how to reference a cell value in the Query Editor, please see this question:

[How can I reference a cell's value in a Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query)