# Excel Power Query: Parameter value from certain cell

Tags: excel, parameter-passing, powerquery, m

I have this power query (it works):

```
(INGCODE) => 

let
    Origine = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://website/ProductDetails.aspx?id=IT01@@7000@@10@@"&(INGCODE))),
    #"Mantenute prime righe" = Table.FirstN(Origine,1),
    #"Rimosse altre colonne" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Mantenute prime righe",{"Caption"})
in
    #"Rimosse altre colonne"
```

The questions are:

1. Can I use a cell value for the "INGCODE" parameter?
2. Can I put the result of the power query in a determined cell?

Comment: For your first question, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query

Answer (score 4):

For 1 - As per Alexis' comment, you need to first define a named range using Excel for your "cell value".  Then the syntax is:

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=rangeName]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

(where rangeName is your named range).

For 2 - Right-click the query in the Workbook Queries pane and choose Load To ... Then under "Select where the data should be loaded to" choose a specific worksheet and cell.

Comment: Is the solution for doing step 1 with an External Source (`SharePoint.Files...`) similar enough to edit into the answer here (if you know it) or do you think it'd be worth asking as a separate question?