# PowerQuery use a cell values in a URL

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following PowerQuery code. Which collects some data from MSFT in yahoo finance.

I have a cell `A1` for example which I would like to put `MSFT`, `GOOG` or another symbol. How can I change it so that when I change `A1` it will automatically redownload for the new symbol?

```
let  Quelle = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=MSFT+Balance+Sheet&annual")),

    Data = Quelle{1}[Data],

    FirstRowHeader = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data)

in  FirstRowHeader
```

Using; `$A$1` did not work.

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=$A$1+Balance+Sheet&annual
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query), you can load in a cell value if you make it a named range.

The first step is to name your cell `A1`. Let's name it `Ticker`. You can name it by typing in the name in the upper left box when the cell is selected

[image: Named Range]

Then your query will look like this:

```
let
    Ticker = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Ticker"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    Quelle = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s="&Ticker&"+Balance+Sheet&annual")),
    Data = Quelle{1}[Data],
    FirstRowHeader = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data)
in  FirstRowHeader
```