# PowerQuery - Dynamic Parameter in ODBC SQL Where Clause

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, parameter-passing, powerquery

I'm trying a different approach to a similar question I've asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72369365/excel-using-cell-value-as-pass-through-date-odbc-sql-powerquery); I have managed to create a dynamic parameter in my PowerQuery Editor which displays a date value entered in an Excel table. The Advanced Editor for the Date Parameter looks like this:

```
(
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DATE_RANGE"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"START_DATE", type date}, {"END_DATE", 
type date}}),
START_DATE = #"Changed Type"{0}[START_DATE]
in
START_DATE
)
meta [IsParameterQuery=true, Type="Any", IsParameterQueryRequired=true]
```

The parameter name is "StartDateValue".

Now, trying to use this parameter value in my OBDC `WHERE` clause I have tried the following:

```
WHERE A."CREATED_DTM" = :StartDateValue
```

Which leaves me with a "`ORA-01008: not all variables bound`" error code. How would I get this parameter value to work in my clause and what am I missing?

Comment: did you try "WHERE A."CREATED_DTM" = '" & StartDateValue & "'"

i use in SQL query **AND ACTION_DATE between '" & firstdate & "' and '" & lastdate & "'**

another issue is the date format in your DB. mine is like 2022-01-01, so you have to convert it to the the same format in the Parameters...