# Supplied file path must be a valid absolute path when referring to CurrentWorkbook in power query

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

I am new to power query and have been trying you use a cell value as a parameter in the where clause of my SQL query.  Following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query) on how to reference the value of a cell in a power query I have been able to implement GetValue which when called will return a valid result.  In my case, the result is an address string i.e. 1/3 Smith Street.  However when I try to use this in filtered Rows (what my searching pointed to as the solution) I get the following error:

> DataFormat.Error: The supplied file path must be a valid absolute path.
>   Details:
>      1/3 - 3/3 Smith Street

I have tried CurrentWorkbook instead of Workbook.  My searching yielded mainly references to url references.

The error is from the below line as if I manually type the function result then it works.  I have also tried putting the function in Text.From() but didn't help.

```
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [GroupName] = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(GetValue("pCurrentGroup"))))
```

I think I am missing something simple as the linked article was selected as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Gahh as soon as I posted I thought of something new to try.. After removing everything except for the function it works!  The functioning code is as follows:

```
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [GroupName] = GetValue("pCurrentGroup"))
```

I guess I was following the instructions too blindly.