# Reference Cell in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

I was looking for preparing a stock chart file. In this file, I want to have an ability to retrieve stock price when I change code. (for example from AMZN to GOOG) after doing so it should change the price. For this, I am using power query function where I have pulled historical data also. I have the excel sheet ready but problem is that I need to manually change code by going into Advance editor mode in power query. I thought to reference Cell A1 in sheet so I just need to change the code in A1 cell and it refresh the price. Is it possible? Please help me. I am using excel 2016.

Thanks,
Sharmil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reference a cell's value in a Power Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-a-power-query)

Comment: I had already checked this but could not able to get solution after doing steps suggested so I have raised question again

Answer (score 1):

Certainly,you should convert cell A1 to table(press Ctrl+T)，and use`= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourTableName"]}[Content]` to reference A1.