# Power query: create a customized column with maths and cell reference

Tags: powerquery

Using Excel powerquery:

I have the colum "index" (it's an index colum):

I want to add a new colum, a customized index. The value of its rows should the same as "index" colum + value of cell A1 from sheet 2 in same book.

Tried with

```
 #"custom index" = Table.AddColumn(#"amount", "customindexo", each [index]+sheet2!A1)
```

Tried also

```
 #"custom index" = Table.AddColumn(#"amount", "customindexo", each [index]+ Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(GetValue("sheet2!A1"))))
```

No sucess. These are my first steps in powerquery. After hours researching I'm not able to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a cell value into the query editor [as shown in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-powerquery), you need your cell value to be named (shows up in the Name Manager under the Formulas tab).

Once the cell is named, then you can reference it:

```
#"custom index" = Table.AddColumn(#"amount", "customindexo",
    each [index] + Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=cellName]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```