# Set or Save Single value (or parameter) to a cell inside excel from Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have seen a number of posts/questions aiming to extract a single value from an excel cell.

I seem unable to do the reverse, save a single value to a designated cell. I have off course been able to save the result of a query (a whole table) to a given location in an Excel sheet, but can't seem to update a single value.

Is there also any way(s) to do this from within the Power Query code itself without having to load a whole query.

I found that PowerQuery provides built-in parameters:
[Power Query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-query-parameters)

However, while I can set these parameters manually (see tutorial linked above, parameters can be defined through the GUI), I cannot seem to figure out how they can be set programmatically.

In brief, I would like to keep track of when was the last update of the data model run to see if the analysis should be run again or not.

Being able to save parameters and update them each time the query is run would be very useful.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot save a single value to a cell. You can save an entire table that is comprised of a single cell, which is almost as good.  You can set ranges programmatically and read them in powerquery so it is not really necessary to be able to set the value of parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26989279/how-can-i-reference-a-cells-value-in-powerquery